# Does 暗闇へ make sense?

Tags: syntax, japanese-to-english

I'm wondering if it translates to "into darkness" directly as a response to something like "Where are we going?" Or possibly as a title for a poem?

I found one example. 暗闇へのワルツ Waltz into Darkness as a literal translation and just wondering if I remove のワルツ if it still makes sense...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

「暗闇{くらやみ}へ」 makes perfect sense as a title and so does 「暗闇の中へ」.

In fact, 「[Noun] + へ」 is a fairly common construct for titles.  Very short phrases ending with particles in general are common for titles.  Titles do not need to sound/look like prose in Japanese.

We often hear/see 「空{そら}へ」、「明日{あした}へ」、「未来{みらい}へ」、「夢{ゆめ}の中{なか}へ」, etc.